# class constructor cannot be accessed by outside package

Tags: java, class, permissions, package, processing

so i can't find a question already asked that answers my exact problem. I have a package that i wrote in eclipse that i exported as a jar library to use in the processing ide. in processing i have a sketch that has a class that calls a class that is in the package. when i try to compile i get this error:

```
Pirate(processing.core.PApplet,java.lang.String,processing.core.PVector,float,float,int,int) is not public in fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate; cannot be accessed from outside package
[javac]   fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate pirate1 = new fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate(this, "Pirate", pinPoint, pWidth, pHeight, 1, 1).displayPirate();
```

does anyone know why i can't access the class? I have both the class and constructor set as `public`, so i'm not sure why the class can't be accessed. any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CONSTRUCTOR CODE:**

```
package fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits;

import processing.core.*;

public class Pirate {
   public String pirateClass;
    int classId;
    PVector pinPoint;
    float width;
    float height;
    int id;
    PApplet parent;

    public Pirate(processing.core.PApplet _parent, String _pirateClass, PVector _pinPoint,
        float _width, float _height, int _classId, int _id) {
        parent = _parent;
        pirateClass = _pirateClass;
        classId = _classId;
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        pinPoint = _pinPoint;
        id = _id;
    }

    public void displayPirate() {
        parent.fill(13, 183, 20, 255);
        parent.stroke(7, 59, 9, 255);
        parent.rect(this.pinPoint.x-this.width/2, (float)(this.pinPoint.y-this.height*.75), this.width, this.height);
    }

}
```

**CODE CALLING PIRATE CLASS:**

```
fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate pirate1 = new fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate(this, "Pirate", pinPoint, pWidth, pHeight, 1, 1).displayPirate();
```

Comment: Showing some code would help. The error is saying that the constructor is **not** public.

Comment: Can you show us the constructor code?

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple overloaded constructors and you are calling the one that is private? Please check the signature. Also, showing the code would be of great help.

Comment: codes up let me know if yo need anything else

Comment: Have you tried clean and replaced the jar with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Pirate class is 1:1 like shown, then I suspect you have an old version in classpath somewhere. Double-check the classpath for old versions, both .java and .class.

Comment: apparently i have to explicitly add the library to the project through a menu option instead of simply replacing the file in the project folder

Answer (score 4):

try to create public default constructor in Pirate class and try to call it as:

```
public class Pirate{
 public Pirate () {}

  ....
}
```

calling code:

```
fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate emptyPirate1 =  new fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate();
```

And check you still get the same error msg?

Comment: i tried that and it gave me a cannot find symbol error. i added the default public constructor and used the like of code you provided.

Comment: Is your jar in the class path? your jar must be visible to classpath inorder to use it. not sure what IDE you use, but in eclipse you can add jar by right click the project and build properties and library and add external jar.

Comment: That's the issue, the constructor must be explicitly declared! +1

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is your problem, but it is a problem and too long for a comment - you should replace;

```
fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate pirate1 = new fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate(this, "Pirate", pinPoint, pWidth, pHeight, 1, 1).displayPirate();
```

with:

```
fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate pirate1 = new fsg.pvzclone.pirateunits.Pirate(this, "Pirate", pinPoint, pWidth, pHeight, 1, 1);
pirate1.displayPirate();
```

Since `displayPirate` returns nothing, not a pirate.